# C++ how do Iget the correct method called?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class MobileContract
{
private:
    string _planID;
    string _contractID;
    PhoneModel _phoneModel;
public:
    MobileContract(const string planID,const string contractID,const PhoneModel &phoneModel);
    virtual double calcPlanPhonePrice();
    virtual void display();
};


class RoadshowContract : public MobileContract
{
private:
    double rsPhoneDiscount;
public:
    RoadshowContract(string planID, string contractID, PhoneModel& phoneModel, double rsPhoneDiscount);
    double calcPlanPhonePrice();
    void display();
};
```

Then, in my main file:

```
std::vector<MobileContract> vect = {
        MobileContract("planA","0", PhoneModel("800","Blue",900.50)),
        MobileContract("planB","1", PhoneModel("750c","Beige",500)),
        RoadshowContract("planC","2", PhoneModel("2110","Red",1000), 50 ),
        RoadshowContract("planA","3", PhoneModel("300","Green",1000), 50)  
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
                    vect[i].calcPlanPhonePrice();
                    vect[i].display();
                    cout << "=============================" << endl;
                }
```

calcPlanPhonePrice and display  from the base class is called. I need them to be called from their specifc types. How do I do that? Also if possible avoid pointers

Answer (score 4):

`vect` stores `MobileContract`, not `RoadshowContract`. It's simple as that. Since `MobileContract` is a public base class of `RoadshowContract`, attempting to stor them in `vect` *slices* the `RoadshowContract`.

You *must* use pointers, but smart pointers are an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Please beware:** You cannot store polymorphic objects in such a manner, you'll have to use pointers instead!

If you want to store both `MobileContract` and `RoadshowContract` in the same vector, you have to use `std::vector<MobileContract *>` or better yet `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MobileContract>>`

**Example using smart pointers (requires C++11 or newer)**

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MobileContract>> vect = {
    std::make_shared<MobileContract>("planA", "0", PhoneModel("800","Blue",900.50)),
    std::make_shared<MobileContract>("planB","1", PhoneModel("750c","Beige",500)),
    std::static_pointer_cast<MobileContract>(std::make_shared<RoadshowContract>("planC","2", PhoneModel("2110","Red",1000), 50 )),
    std::static_pointer_cast<MobileContract>(std::make_shared<RoadshowContract>("planA","3", PhoneModel("300","Green",1000), 50))
};

for (auto & x : vect) {
    x->calcPlanPhonePrice();
    x->display();
    cout << "=============================" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Assumes use of C++11, which OP didn't mention.

Comment: @Steve, added comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you positively, definitely, absolutely don't want to use pointers (**why?**), you could accomplish it using two different vectors:

```
std::vector<MobileContract> mobvect = {
        MobileContract("planA","0", PhoneModel("800","Blue",900.50)),
        MobileContract("planB","1", PhoneModel("750c","Beige",500))
}

std::vector<RoadshowContract> roadshowvect = {
        RoadshowContract("planC","2", PhoneModel("2110","Red",1000), 50 ),
        RoadshowContract("planA","3", PhoneModel("300","Green",1000), 50)  
};
```

Then just iterate through each - in real life you'd probably want to make this a single method and call it on each vector, but for the purposes of this question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mobvect .size(); i++) {
                mobvect [i].calcPlanPhonePrice();
                mobvect [i].display();
                cout << "=============================" << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < roadshowvect .size(); i++) {
                roadshowvect [i].calcPlanPhonePrice();
                roadshowvect [i].display();
                cout << "=============================" << endl;
}
```

Note that depending on which version of C++ you're using, there are potential improvements such as using range-based `for`, `auto` etc. Or using smart pointers, as described in other answers (not sure if you'd class that under your desire to not use pointers)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to make sure you are overwriting the funcitions. Then your inhereited class would be something like:

```
class RoadshowContract : public MobileContract
{
private:
    double rsPhoneDiscount;
public:
    RoadshowContract(string planID, string contractID, PhoneModel& phoneModel, double rsPhoneDiscount);
    double calcPlanPhonePrice() override;
    void display() override;
};
```

However, your vector is of type MobileContract, therefore, the method called will be that always. To change this you have to use pointers and polymorphism. Then, your main cpp will be like:

```
std::vector<MobileContract*> vect = {
        new MobileContract("planA","0" ),
        new MobileContract("planB","1"),
        new RoadshowContract("planC","2", 50 ),
        new RoadshowContract("planA","3", 50)  
        };

for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
    vect[i]->calcPlanPhonePrice();
    vect[i]->display();
    cout << "=============================" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a [tag:C++11] feature.

Comment: `override` is a comment, mostly. The compiler will check if it's correct, but it merely tells the reader that the overridden function exists in the base class. We already knew that from the question.